# Using python rdflib parsers without the graph object

Tags: python, parsing, tokenize, rdflib

Loading RDF data in Python looks like this:

```
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse("demo.nt", format="nt")
```

But what about using the format parsers standalone as streaming parsers, getting a stream of parsed tokens? Can someone give me a hint/code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NT parser follows a paradigm of using a "sink" (not a sink vertex) to store triples as they are parsed. I believe the tokens you are looking for are actually triples because the default [NT Parser uses the NTriplesParser](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/rdflib/plugins/parsers/nt.py).

You could use the same method as the example below to [override NTSink](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/rdflib/plugins/parsers/nt.py#L7).

This example will load up a [test NT formatted file](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/test/nt/anons-01.nt) then `print` a line of text each time a line is parsed. Instead of printing a line, you could execute the method you are missing.

`example.py`: Requires a file in the same directory named `./anons-01.nt`

```
from rdflib.plugins.parsers.ntriples import NTriplesParser, Sink
# The NTriplesParser is what is used for a format="nt" parsing as found:
#  https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/rdflib/plugins/parsers/nt.py#L2

# Example NT file from:
#  https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/test/nt/anons-01.nt


class StreamSink(Sink):
    """
    A sink is used to store the results of parsing, this almost matches the sink
    example shown in ntriples:
      https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/395a40101fe133d97f454ee61da0fc748a93b007/rdflib/plugins/parsers/ntriples.py#L43
    """
    def triple(self, s, p, o):
        self.length += 1
        print "Stream of triples s={s}, p={p}, o={o}".format(s=s, p=p, o=o)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a new parser and try to parse the example NT file.
    n = NTriplesParser(StreamSink())
    with open("./anons-01.nt", "r") as anons:
        n.parse(anons)
```

`output`:

```
Stream of triples s=N33bb017ce2c340999d2aa6a071d79678, p=http://example.org/#p, o=http://example.org/#q
Stream of triples s=N33bb017ce2c340999d2aa6a071d79678, p=http://example.org/#r, o=http://example.org/#s
Stream of triples s=Nb8d195e0586f42c4bcc703be897c74fa, p=http://example.org/#p, o=http://example.org/#q
Stream of triples s=Nb8d195e0586f42c4bcc703be897c74fa, p=http://example.org/#r, o=N235a8c8b4f91453892da284cb0c490e0
Stream of triples s=N235a8c8b4f91453892da284cb0c490e0, p=http://example.org/#s, o=http://example.org/#t
```

Comment: could you take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493215/parse-rdf-file-python)?